# Mapa offline no Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Estou fazendo uma aplicação na qual usando mapa do Google e pode ficar sem acesso a internet. Sem acesso a internet o sistema de mapa da Google não funciona.

Perguntas:

1º Sei que tem como gravar em cache algumas informações do mapa da Google, mas como que faz isso no desenvolvimento? Vi que no aplicativo maps que vem no Android ele salva em cache.

2º Existe alguma empresa que fornece os mapas off line?

3º Existe algum outra solução?

Att

Comment: Já é uma ideia http://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2015/11/como-baixar-mapas-offline-no-google-maps-para-android.html

Comment: Otto, no desenvolvimento de um novo app, é possível adicionar o mapa off line dentro da aplicação?

Comment: Mestre não fui a fundo nisso, porém compartilhei parte do conhecimento que já tenho, ou seja o google maps consegue trabalhar com mapas offline. Agora questao de ver como utilizar isto em seu benefício.